# How to migrate mongdb users using Passportjs to Couchdb?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm building an offline-first app but didn't research on it until now. My current setup is the app uses Angular(1.x) and communicates to my server using NodeJS on a MongoDB Database. I'm using PassportJS for my authentication at the moment.

I'd like to migrate all my date to CouchDB and use PouchDB on my app.

1. How do I migrate from my current setup to PouchDB to CouchDB?
2. How can I authenticate my users after migration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How do I migrate  my current setup to CouchDB

### Moving data

To export/import data from mongo to couch, you can simply follow [these steps](https://developer.ibm.com/dwblog/2013/exporting-mongodb-couchdb-cloudant/). Basically, you just dump your jsons and push them in Couch.

### Structuring data

In CouchDB, there's no collections. Usually, to split your data into "collections", you simply add a special key to identify the  collection. It can be `type` or `collection` for example.

### Permissions

I'm not aware of the permissions system in MongoDB but basically, you can only define permissions at database level. So if you want some people to access certain documents, you can either use an application layer to handle permissions  or you can split your documents with the `per-user-pattern`(One database per user and one global database without all public data).

---

## Authentification

You can still use passportjs with CouchDB([see this example](https://github.com/pin3da/passport-couchdb)).

Also, you can use CouchDB authentification system which is builtin. Therefore, it has some limitations(eg: you can't expire someone's token and there's not builtin password recovery system).

Comment: Thank you. I'll try the moving and structuring of data. I have read some articles regarding superlogin with passportjs. Thaks for giving me the idea on  how to migrate.